# como se que esta funcionando AWE?

Tags: sql-server-2005, awe

Tengo un servidor con 8GB de RAM de 32 bits, instale windows server 2003 enterprise y sql server 2005 enterprise, el Sistema Operativo reconoce los 8GB, pero el Sql Server solo usaba 1.6 GB de memoria, entonces agregue al boot.ini el parametro /PAE y en Sql Server le habilite AWE de 1GB a 5GB, despues de reiniciar el servidor el Sistema que usa la BD estaba mas rapido mejoro bastante, pero en memoria el Sql Server solo usa 100 MB, veo la cantidad de memoria usada en el Administrador de Tareas de Windows, y no se si esta funcionando AWE o que sucedio?

**Rough translation:**

I have a server with 8GB of RAM 32-bit, install windows server 2003 enterprise and sql server 2005 enterprise, the operating system recognizes the 8GB, but the SQL Server only using 1.6 GB of memory, then add to boot.ini the parameter / PAE and will enable AWE Sql Server 1GB to 5GB, after rebooting the server using the database system was faster, the better lot, but in memory the SQL Server only uses 100 MB, I see the amount of memory used in Manager Windows Tasks, and not if AWE is running or what happened?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AWE/PAE increases the amount of physical *system* memory to a theoretical maximum of 64GB, but the amount of virtual *process* memory is still hard-restricted to 4GB.

Comment: look in the windows task manager performance tab USE OF PF is consuming 5.65 GB, is that the AWE is working correctly? or should not appear there?

Comment: That's the page file (swap space). The value that matters for seeing if PAE is working is the available physical memory.

Comment: Said Physical memory (KB):
Total: 8383532
Available: 2311468
System Cache: 2593864

Comment: Why did I say "available" when I clearly meant "total". Yes, looks like PAE is active.

Comment: Your statement is true vis-a-vis PAE, but AWE does allow a process to access more than 4 GB of memory. (Only 4 GB can be seen by the process at a time, so it has to choose which 4 GB to look at, but the rest is still there. The key is in the abbrevation: "Address Windowing Extensions"; AWE allows a process a 4 GB window into a larger amount of memory).  SQL uses this to access more than 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Run `dbcc memorystatus` on the SQL server; AWE memory does not show up in a process's working set (and thus task manager).  See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191481.aspx